# How do we implement @Override in J2ME?

Tags: class, java-me

Thank you @Telmo for pointing out that we have to use FileConnection instead of File class functions in J2ME. How can I override functions in J2ME?

Comment: Search for FileConnection

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to read/write text file in j2me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204373/how-to-read-write-text-file-in-j2me)

Comment: I am aware of FileConnection and Connectors, but is there any equivalent class is my question.

Comment: Please, read the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/cldc1.1/jsr139/