# J2ME Exception opening a file: Root is not accessible

Tags: permissions, java-me, file-connection

I'm trying to read a txt file following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204373/how-to-read-write-text-file-in-j2me) but I can't get it to work. It shows this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Root is not accessible
 - com/sun/io/j2me/file/Protocol..unknown.(), bci=21
 - com/sun/io/j2me/file/Protocol..unknown.(), bci=424
 - com/sun/io/j2me/file/Protocol..unknown.(), bci=5
 - javax/microedition/io/Connector.open(), bci=73
 - javax/microedition/io/Connector.open(), bci=6
 - javax/microedition/io/Connector.open(), bci=3
```

This is the code:

```
try 
{                    
    fileConnection = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file://home//pi//test.txt", Connector.READ_WRITE);

    if(fileConnection.exists()) 
    {
         int size = (int)fileConnection.fileSize();
         is= fileConnection.openInputStream();
         byte bytes[] = new byte[size];
         is.read(bytes, 0, size);
         String str = new String(bytes, 0, size);

         System.out.println(size);
    }

}
```

I think it has to do with the permissions, but I've set these:

```
javax.microedition.io.Connector.file.read

javax.microedition.io.Connector.file.write

java.io.FilePermission "file://*" "read,write"
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Found the solution by myself, the path does not start with 'home', but with 'root1'

Answer (score 0):

Some/most JavaME-enabled phones doesn't allow access to all folders on the SD card or internal storage.

Try using `String file = "file:///c:/other/test.txt";` or `String file = "file:///e:/other/test.txt";` instead.

Or you can try `String file = System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.memorycard") + "/test.txt";` or `String file = System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.memorycard") + "/other/test.txt";`

The best approach however, is to use code that simply checks for available folders. Some useful examples here:
http://javatechig.com/java/j2me/fileconnection-apis-jsr-75